# How to print Kotlin tests output to console instead of html report?

Tags: kotlin, testing, gradle

I have a Kotlin project configured with Gradle. See [GitHub repository](https://github.com/mxl/kotlin-algorithm/tree/e8283fd399268aa8be54f39ed6470a043c48a859).

It contains one test case:

```
class MergeSortTest {
    @Test
    fun sort() {
        val sorted = arrayOf(1, 3, 2, 4).mergeSorted()
        println(sorted.joinToString(" "))
        assertTrue(sorted.contentEquals(arrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4)))
    }
}
```

When I run tests with `./gradlew check` command I get the following output (non-essential parts are omitted):

```
...
MergeSortTest[jvm] > sort[jvm] FAILED
    java.lang.AssertionError at MergeSortTest.kt:10
...
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':allTests'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///Users/mledin/projects/kotlin-algorithm/build/reports/tests/allTests/index.html
...
```

There is no output from `println()` call and also no `Expected value to be true.` message.

They both are present in html report but it's not convenient to open html report each time.

How can I make `./gradlew check` print all output to console instead of html report?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gradle: How to Display Test Results in the Console in Real Time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963708/gradle-how-to-display-test-results-in-the-console-in-real-time)

Comment: @AnimeshSahu Yes, thanks! But is there a way to avoid other extra output? May be by configuring test task?

Comment: Which type of extra output?

Comment: Does this one help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34766301/suppressing-interactive-output-in-gradle-exec-tasks

Comment: Providing `-i` option to `./gradlew check -i` gives me a ton of other output with INFO logging level which makes reading it more difficult.

Comment: That solution isn't suitable for my case (or I don't know how to apply it).

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55273517/746347):

```
tasks.withType<Test> {
    this.testLogging {
        this.showStandardStreams = true
    }
}
```

Place this snippet in `build.gradle.kts` on top level to enable standard streams output for all test tasks or use it in configuration block for specific compilation:

```
kotlin {
  jvm {
    compilations {
      val test by getting {
        <insert snippet here>
      }
    }
  }
}
```